# custom android analog clock at widget

Tags: android, widget

I work at world analog clock I used android analog clock, it's work at activity but I can't use it at widget,I tired googled it is there any one have idea ?

Comment: but AnalogClock widegt also possible to use in home screen widget?have u try it if then post your code

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following widget classes in Home Screen Widget:

```
* AnalogClock 
* Button 
* Chronometer 
* ImageButton 
* ImageView 
* ProgressBar 
* TextView
```

*Descendants of these classes are not supported*

see an example how we use an AnalogClock widget in Home Screen widget [here](http://pastebin.com/PkaB2sTt)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own widget based on ImageView and create background service to create bitmaps and periodically push them to widget.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
```

* 
 * This widget display an analogic clock with two hands for hours and
 * 
 * minutes.
 */

@RemoteView
public class AnalogClock2 extends View {

```
public AnalogClock2(Context context) {

    super(context);

    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

private Time mCalendar;

private Drawable mHourHand;

private Drawable mMinuteHand;

private Drawable mSecondHand;

private Drawable mDial;

private int mDialWidth;

private int mDialHeight;

private boolean mAttached;

private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

private float mMinutes;

private float mHour;

private boolean mChanged;

Context mContext;
public static  String  mtimezone="Asia/Calcutta";
public AnalogClock2(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

    this(context, attrs, 0);

}

public AnalogClock2(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,

int defStyle) {

    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    Resources r = context.getResources();

//  TypedArray a =

//  context.obtainStyledAttributes(

//  attrs, R.styleable.AnalogClock, defStyle, 0);

    mContext = context;

    // mDial =
    // a.getDrawable(com.android.internal.R.styleable.AnalogClock_dial);

    // if (mDial == null) {

    mDial = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.widgetdial);

    // }

    // mHourHand =
    // a.getDrawable(com.android.internal.R.styleable.AnalogClock_hand_hour);

    // if (mHourHand == null) {

    mHourHand = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.widgethour);

    // }

    // mMinuteHand =
    // a.getDrawable(com.android.internal.R.styleable.AnalogClock_hand_minute);

    // if (mMinuteHand == null) {

    mMinuteHand = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.widgetminute);

    mSecondHand = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.widgetminute);

    // }

    mCalendar = new Time();

    mDialWidth = mDial.getIntrinsicWidth();

    mDialHeight = mDial.getIntrinsicHeight();

}
public static void timezone(String timezone){
      mtimezone=timezone;
}

@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {

    super.onAttachedToWindow();

    if (!mAttached) {

        mAttached = true;

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);

        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED);

        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED);

        getContext().registerReceiver(mIntentReceiver, filter, null, mHandler);

    }

    // NOTE: It's safe to do these after registering the receiver since the
    // receiver always runs

    // in the main thread, therefore the receiver can't run before this
    // method returns.

    // The time zone may have changed while the receiver wasn't registered,
    // so update the Time

    //mCalendar = new Time();
    mCalendar = new Time(mtimezone);
    // Make sure we update to the current time

    onTimeChanged();

    counter.start();

}

@Override
protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {

    super.onDetachedFromWindow();

    if (mAttached) {

        counter.cancel();

        getContext().unregisterReceiver(mIntentReceiver);

        mAttached = false;

    }

}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);

    int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);

    int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);

    int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    float hScale = 1.0f;

    float vScale = 1.0f;

    if (widthMode != MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED && widthSize < mDialWidth) {

        hScale = (float) widthSize / (float) mDialWidth;

    }

    if (heightMode != MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED && heightSize < mDialHeight) {

        vScale = (float) heightSize / (float) mDialHeight;

    }

    System.out.println("***********************HAI****************");

    float scale = Math.min(hScale, vScale);

    setMeasuredDimension(resolveSize((int) (mDialWidth * scale), widthMeasureSpec),

    resolveSize((int) (mDialHeight * scale), heightMeasureSpec));

}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {

    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    mChanged = true;

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    super.onDraw(canvas);

    // // here changes on every tick//////

    // / ////

    // / //

    // //////

    // // ///

    // //

    boolean changed = mChanged;

    if (changed) {

        mChanged = false;

    }

    boolean seconds = mSeconds;

    if (seconds) {

        mSeconds = false;

    }

    int availableWidth = 100;

    int availableHeight = 200;

    int x = availableWidth / 2;

    int y = availableHeight / 2;

    final Drawable dial = mDial;

    int w = dial.getIntrinsicWidth();

    int h = dial.getIntrinsicHeight();

    boolean scaled = false;

    if (availableWidth < w || availableHeight < h) {

        scaled = true;

        float scale = Math.min((float) availableWidth / (float) w,

        (float) availableHeight / (float) h);

        canvas.save();

        canvas.scale(scale, scale, x, y);

    }

    if (changed) {

        dial.setBounds(x - (w / 2), y - (h / 2), x + (w / 2), y + (h / 2));

    }

    dial.draw(canvas);

    canvas.save();

    canvas.rotate(mHour / 12.0f * 360.0f, x, y);

    final Drawable hourHand = mHourHand;

    if (changed) {

        w = hourHand.getIntrinsicWidth();

        h = hourHand.getIntrinsicHeight();

        hourHand.setBounds(x - (w / 2), y - (h / 3), x + (w / 2), y + (h / 3));

    }

    hourHand.draw(canvas);

    canvas.restore();

    canvas.save();

    canvas.rotate(mMinutes / 60.0f * 360.0f, x, y);

    // canvas.rotate(mSecond, x, y);

    final Drawable minuteHand = mMinuteHand;

    if (changed) {

        w = minuteHand.getIntrinsicWidth();

        h = minuteHand.getIntrinsicHeight();

        minuteHand.setBounds(x - (w / 2), y - (h / 3), x + (w / 2), y + (h / 3));

    }

    minuteHand.draw(canvas);

    canvas.restore();

    canvas.save();

    canvas.rotate(mSecond, x, y);

    // minuteHand = mMinuteHand;

    if (seconds) {

        w = mSecondHand.getIntrinsicWidth();

        h = mSecondHand.getIntrinsicHeight();

        mSecondHand.setBounds(x - (w / 2), y - (h / 3), x + (w / 2), y + (h / 3));

    }

    mSecondHand.draw(canvas);

    canvas.restore();

    if (scaled) {

        canvas.restore();

    }

}

MyCount counter = new MyCount(10000, 1000);

public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {

    public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {

        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {

        counter.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        mCalendar.setToNow();

        int hour = mCalendar.hour;

        int minute = mCalendar.minute;

        int second = mCalendar.second;

        mSecond = 6.0f * second;

        mSeconds = true;

        // mChanged = true;

        AnalogClock2.this.invalidate();

        // Toast.makeText(mContext, "text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}

boolean mSeconds = false;

float mSecond = 0;

private void onTimeChanged() {

    mCalendar.setToNow();

    int hour = mCalendar.hour+4;

    int minute = mCalendar.minute+15;

    int second = mCalendar.second;

    mMinutes = minute + second / 60.0f;

    mHour = hour + mMinutes / 60.0f;

    mChanged = true;

}

private final BroadcastReceiver mIntentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED)) {

            String tz = intent.getStringExtra("time-zone");

            mCalendar = new Time(TimeZone.getTimeZone(tz).getID());

        }
        mCalendar = new Time(mtimezone);
        onTimeChanged();

        invalidate();

    }

};
```

}

Comment: i have custom analog clock like this.. and how to prepare widget from this clock?